# How to bind custom class object's property in a data trigger of control template of button?

Tags: wpf

Toggle Button has the below style.

```
<Style x:Key="SearchDataControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate >
                    <Grid x:Name="grd" Height="80" Width="120" Margin="5">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="baseColor" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Glow" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Opacity="0">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.505,1.291" RadiusY="0.853" RadiusX="0.853">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF00BBFF"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF939393" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00C1C1C1" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#A5A4E0EB" Offset="0.28"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#53818AD5" Offset="0.543"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#7C92B5E0" Offset="0.453"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Glass" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Opacity="0.8">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.514,1.158" StartPoint="0.514,-0.101">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.149"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFABABAB" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7A7A7A" Offset="0.414"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF909090" Offset="0.61"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="imgDependent" Visibility="Visible" Source="D:\Elektra Main\SearchPanel\DynamicSearchPanel\SearchProvider\Dependent.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Image x:Name="imgOptional" Visibility="Visible" Source="D:\Elektra Main\SearchPanel\DynamicSearchPanel\SearchProvider\Optional.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Description}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Glow" Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="baseColor" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDependentElement}" Value="{x:Null}" >
                            <Setter TargetName="imgDependent" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOptionalElement}" Value="{x:Null}" >
                            <Setter TargetName="imgOptional" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
```

Question is Togglebutton DataContext is a custom class which has the properties IsOptionalElement and IsDependentElement. I have set two datatriggers which are not working?

```
public class SearchData
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SearchDataType Type { get; set; }

    public string Validator { get; set; }

    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public object SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> ComboBoxItemSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int DefaultSelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public bool IsYesOrNo { get; set; }

    public OnValidateText OnValidate { get; set; }

    public string OptionalElement { get; set; }

    public string DependentElement { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisplayed { get; set; }

    public bool HasValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the wrong `Value` in your `DataTrigger`.

Are `IsDependentElement` and `IsOptionalElement` plain "bool" variables, or are they nullable?

I created a ViewModel containing "bool" properties, and then changed the DataTrigger to Value="False", and it collapsed the image when False, and showed when True.

Comment: IsDependent Element is a custom class object , it is not a boolean. If it is not null then image should be displayed.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your custom class into your question, thanks...and the XAML where you create your ToggleButtons.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to dynamically create ToggleButtons, and how you add them into the tree.

Comment: ToggleButton btnChild = new ToggleButton();
                    btnChild.Content = childDescription;                    
                    btnChild.Tag = childDescription;
                    btnChild.Style = Resources["DependentControlStyle"] as Style;
                    btnChild.DataContext = _originaldataList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Description == childDescription);
                    btnChild.Background = new SolidColorBrush(randomColor);
                    pnlWrapSearchMembers.Children.Add(btnChild);